# Loading test pages within a unit test in the firefox-addon-sdk

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

My add-on involves the user interface, and so to test it I decided to simply have a html page which will load and the tester can follow some instructions on the page.

Here is an example of loading the page:

```
exports["test interaction"] = function(assert, done) {
  require("sdk/tabs").tabs.open({
    url: "./tests/test-page.html",
    onClose: function(tab) {
      assert.pass("Done page test");
      done();
  });
};
```

However, after about 16 seconds the tests will always fail with two error messages:

```
fail:
Timed out (after: START)
```

and

```
fail:
Should not be any unexpected tabs open
```

Furthermore, and *more importantly*, my addon does not work at all using `cfx test`, while it works using `cfx run` on the same test pages.

Is there a way to load some HTML testing pages using `cfx test`?

Answer (score 2):

Adding tab.close() before done() will fix the "Should not be any unexpected tabs open" error.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is listen for messages from the tab you opened and then manually close the tab. You can send messages by injecting a content script into the tab, and communicating back. Something like:

1. page is opened
2. page runs some tests, and on completion or error, sends data via window.postMessage to the content script
3. the content script relays these results back to the tab worker
4. the tab worker closes the tab

Comment: The page itself doesn't run any tests because the test is dependant entirely on user interaction. I explicitly want to test the user doing something. Although, perhaps I can have *some* of it done automatically - but certainly there is *far less* coding involved in having the user test it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant running unit tests. The sdk's testing module is actually just targeted at unit tests, not functional / manual tests like you seem to want.